# how to pass alt attribute to a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have this portion of code in a jsp class

```
<ul class="primi">
    <li>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/products">

            <img class="small-image" src="images/product1.jpg" alt="product1">
        </a>
    </li>
```

in products servlet I have to work with alt attribute of img (in this case product1). How can I pass this attribute to the servlet??
I tried

```
request.getAttribute("alt")
```

and

```
request.getParameter("alt")
```

but didn't work.

Comment: I have to pass the value of alt attribute to a servlet...where I have to put setAttribute??

Comment: The browser does not send that data.

Comment: can you try `setAttribute` rather than `getAttribute` in servlet.

Comment: You have to set the `alt` attribute in servlet, which is read by the jsp which then render the HTML.

Comment: if I used setAttribute I should know the value of alt in advance...instead in Servlet depending on the value I need to do different things.

Comment: You can get the `alt` attribute using Javascript. So, instead of surrounding the `img` with anchor `a`, you can call a `onclick` javascript method with the URL, then get the [`alt` attribute of that image](http://codepen.io/learningloop/pen/YXjoqx/) and pass it as URL parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter on your url like below:

```
   <ul class="primi">
        <li>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/products?alt=product1">

                <img class="small-image" src="images/product1.jpg" alt="product1">
            </a>
        </li>
```